# SQL: Which person took which test or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to people and exams they did or did not participate in
I can't figure it out for some reason

Tables

```
 EXAM:        ID, NAME,      ...etc
 PERSON:      ID, NAME,      ...etc
 PERSON_EXAM: ID, PERSON_ID, EXAM_ID, ...etc
```

Desired result

```
PERSON_ID    EXAM_ID     PERSON_EXAM_ID
1            1           1
1            2           NULL                  
1            3           2
2            1           NULL
2            2           NULL
2            3           3
```

Currently I did this

```
  select 
     p.ID as PERSON_ID, 
     e.ID as EXAM_ID,
     (select pe.ID from PERSON_EXAM pe 
      where pe.PERSON_ID = p.ID and pe.EXAM_ID = e.ID) as PERSON_EXAM_ID
  from PERSON p, EXAM e
```

But I fear it will be slow
I tried to join two tables with one but I can't do that for some reason as

```
    select p.ID as PERSON_ID, e.ID as EXAM_ID, pe.ID as PERSON_EXAM_ID
    from PERSON p, EXAM e 
    left join PERSON_EXAM pe on 
       p.ID = pe.PERSON_ID and // 'p' isn't recognized because the join is on 'e'
       e.ID = pe.ITEM_ID
```

Comment: You have implicit joins in your query. You should heavily consider getting rid of these. `JOIN` syntax has been in SQL Server for decades now.

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins! (Explicit join chains are evaluated before implicit comma joins.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  Just use the correct syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
select p.ID as PERSON_ID, e.ID as EXAM_ID, pe.ID as PERSON_EXAM_ID
from PERSON p cross join
     EXAM e left join
     PERSON_EXAM pe 
     on p.ID = pe.PERSON_ID and 
        e.ID = pe.ITEM_ID;
```

The semantics of the archaic comma mean that the table alias is not recognized in subsequent `on` clauses.

Comment: TIL cross join. Thank you.